# Trouble interpreting information to develop mathematical functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling

[image: Information to interpret]

Context: University coding assignment

So far from this information, I've managed to develop two models:

For the surface zone, I have $T(l)=\frac{-11}{45}l+24$ and for the deep zone, I have $T(l)=2$ where $T$ is the summer temperature in degrees Celsius and $l$ is the latitude in degrees (where $0$ is the equator and $90$ are the poles).

I'm having trouble interpreting this information to develop a linear model for the summer temperature of the seawater ($T$) at the thermocline zone. I know this model will differ from the last two as it will be a function of depth (rather than latitude), but the lack of data is really throwing me.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature in the *thermocline* zone, $T$, is a function of the *surface* temperature, $T_s$, the temperature of the *depth* zone, i.e. $2$, and the depth at which the temperature is calculated, $d,200\le d\le1000$. Since $T$ here varies linearly with $d$, we have$$\frac{T-2}{d-1000}=\frac{T_s-2}{200-1000}$$We get$$T(d,l)=2+\dfrac{(1000-d)(22-\frac{11}{45}l)}{800}$$

Comment: So, essentially, you're saying that $\frac{T_{thermocline}-T_{deep}}{d_{thermocline}-d_{deep}}=\frac{T_{surface}-T_{deep}}{d_{surface}-d_{deep}}$?

Comment: And wouldn't the final equation be $T(d,l)=2+\frac{(d-1000)(\frac{11}{45}l-22)}{800}$?

Comment: @RubyPa Yes, the temperature in _thermocline_ declines linearly with depth $d$ from $T_s$ at $d=200$ to $2$ at $d=1000$. The first equation I wrote describes this relationship. As for the final equation you got, it is the same as mine; check carefully!